# Howto add custom feature to chromium

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm new to chromium development so I admit I'm not familiar with the project's depth and submodules.

I want to create a special build of chromium such as many others have already done (opera, brave, etc).
Based as starting point with chromium, i would want to add to it (native code) the following features:

1. a implementation of adblock
2. a implementation of lastpass.com
3. etc (other features)

I've analysed a bit the code of other browsers, such as brave-core (of BraveBrowser) but to my unfortune, i was unable to find anything on the web about howto start creating your own component(module), at least a few advices.

For example, doing points 1 and 2 above, would mean that "my code" would have to:

- bind to a factory of when a new page (tab) was opened so i can also fire my own code there

but i was unable to figure out how/where to do that.

Are there any guides on the web that i can read?
Or can anyone of you provide me with some guidelines?

Many thanks.

Comment: Chromium is a very big and complex project. The answer to your question is beyond the scope of this site. The only way to get started is to build Chromium and go through the source code. You won't find a-z articles any where for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I figured. Though, any idea if there exist communities or discussion channels/forums where one can ask guidelines and someone reply back?

Comment: Here's the official Chromium developer group: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-dev Also the implementations that you are talking about are extensions. You don't have to modify the source code to build them. Just learn how to make extensions

Comment: @Asesh - i've seen in some other stackoverflow topic that you "have worked on bundling extensions as both extensions and component extensions in our Chromium fork".

if that fork is public, can you please give me the github link or something like that so i can inspect commit-history and learn about how you created components?

Comment: It's not a public repo, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Make your own extensions like Adblock or lastpass or bundle your extensions with your Chromium?

Comment: first thing, i want to create a component extension, that based on username.pass login, to retrieve from some server data about other usernames/passwords - for internal use. and obviously, when navigating to site1 or site2 to fill-in automatically login data for that site, etc.

also to register MutationObservers on various sites, to create alerts/etc directly in the browser about what happened there

Comment: Hmm you don't need to create component extensions to do so. Those things can be done using extensions only. In the context of Chromium, `component extensions are extensions which cannot be uninstalled and are bundled with Chromium`. Again all of those things can be done using extensions only.

Comment: I would prefer it in native code, to be less-possible to be hacked.

Comment: Going to say it again--better use extensions. The architecture of Chromium will make it very difficult for you to do so using native code. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for feedback @Asesh. 
I will keep searching though about means to do it native. :)